# Cant open a file by it's relative path while the code running from docker container

Tags: docker, copy, relative-path, filenotfounderror

I'm looking for help in the issue I have.

In my code I'm trying to open a config file by it's relative path

```
with open("../config/config.json") as json_config:
```

This part works great when I'm running it locally (either command line or IDE)

The folder structure looks like this (the running code is in convertor folder):

[image]

When I'm trying to run the same code from docker container , I'm getting
FileNotFound Error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../config/config.json'
```

my Docker file looks like

```
...
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
...
```

The config.json is correctly copied to container (all the project correctly being copied)

Thanks for helping here !

Comment: you can use a docker volume to mount your current directory, so that you code in container can access it and use relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("config/config.json") as json_config:
```

Forgot that the code is running from the root :)